# Create a new form by pressing a button - PowerApps

Tags: forms, sharepoint, powerapps

I want to be able to use a PowerApp button that would copy a form that allow me to enter multiple rows in a table without needing to exit the screen

[Here I want to press the '+' symbol and repeat the department and Cust_Name fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbXKx.png)

How would I go about doing that or is there an easier route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Collect()](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/function-clear-collect-clearcollect/) to add all the details to a temporary table and display the collection in a gallery.

When the user hits the '+' symbol collect all the info you need and reset the input field.